# Why is std::ranges::views::take using templated type for difference?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Signature of  take is

```
template< ranges::viewable_range R, class DifferenceType >

    requires /* ... */
constexpr ranges::view auto take( R&& r, DifferenceType&& count );
```

It is a minor thing but I wonder why `DifferenceType` is not some ssize type(practically `int64_t` on modern machines).
Is this just to avoid warnings on comparisons of integers of different signednes, or is there some other design reason I am missing.  My intuition that having a fixed type would make error messages easier to read, so I wonder what was the motivation.

If somebody is interested in code example, here it is, it feels a bit artificial since I wanted to keep it short, but it is quite possible to pass wrong type to take argument and then error message is [unreadable](https://godbolt.org/z/qG71Yhh81)(my favorite part is:

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220401/include/c++/12.0.1/bits/atomic_base.h:98:3:
> note: candidate: 'constexpr std::memory_order
> std::operator|(memory_order, __memory_order_modifier)'

).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

auto get_n(){
    return std::string("2");
}

int main() {
    std::vector v {2,3,5,7,11};
    const auto n = get_n(); //oops this is std::string
    auto dont_even = v | std::views::filter([](const int& i){return i%2==1;}) | std::views::take(n);
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", dont_even);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is a minor thing but I wonder why `DifferenceType` is not some ssize
> type(practically `int64_t` on modern machines). Is this just to avoid
> warnings on comparisons of integers of different signednes, or is
> there some other design reason I am missing.

Iterators for different range adaptors have different `difference_type`s. The calculation of `difference_type` is sometimes not as simple as you think.

Taking `iota_view` as an example, the standard deliberately uses [`IOTA-DIFF-T(W)`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota#view-1) to calculate its `difference_type`, which makes the `difference_type` of `iota_view<uint64_t>` is `__int128` and the `difference_type` of `iota_view<__int128>` is even a customized `__detail::__max_diff_type` in listdc++.

This is why the second parameter of `views::take` is a template and not a specific integer type, but note that the standard also has constraints on `DifferenceType` in [[range.take.overview]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.take.overview):

> The name `views​::​take` denotes a range adaptor object
> ([range.adaptor.object]). Let `E` and `F` be expressions, let `T` be
> `remove_­cvref_­t<decltype((E))>`, and let `D` be
> `range_­difference_­t<decltype((E))>`. **If `decltype((F))` does not model
> `convertible_­to<D>`**, `views​::​take(E, F)` is ill-formed.

which requires that the `DifferenceType` must be convertible to `R`'s `difference_type`, which also allows you to

```
auto r = std::views::iota(0)
       | std::views::take(std::integral_constant<int, 42>{});
```

Comment: ah I did not think of iota, great example/reason, do you know why it is not restricted(using requires) to integerish types (maybe because some of the diff types are nonstandard?)

Comment: Integer-class types are not necessarily built-in integer types, they can also be implementation-defined class types, as introduced by [P1522](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1522r1.pdf). However, the introduction of these integer-class types also brought some issues, which have been resolved by [P2393](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2393r1.html) in C++23.